# KQL How to merge result rows post mv-apply to get the right count

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Working with KQL

Given this data set

```
let MyTable = datatable (VMID:int, ID:string, Type:string, features:dynamic, scanner:dynamic)
[
    1, "ID-1", "Windows", dynamic([
        {"name": "name1", "value": true},
        {"name": "name2", "value": false},
        {"name": "name3", "value": true}
    ]), dynamic([
        {"name": "s1", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s2", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s3", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s4", "expiry": false}
    ]),
    2, "ID-1", "Windows", dynamic([
        {"name": "name1", "value": true},
        {"name": "name2", "value": false},
        {"name": "name3", "value": true}
    ]), dynamic([
        {"name": "s1", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s2", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s3", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s4", "expiry": true}
    ]),
    3, "ID-1", "Linux", dynamic([
        {"name": "name1", "value": true},
        {"name": "name2", "value": false},
        {"name": "name3", "value": true}
    ]), dynamic([
        {"name": "s1", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s2", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s3", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s4", "expiry": false}
    ]),
    4, "ID-2", "Windows", dynamic([
        {"name": "name1", "value": true},
        {"name": "name2", "value": false},
        {"name": "name3", "value": true}
    ]), dynamic([
        {"name": "s1", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s2", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s3", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s4", "expiry": true}
    ]),
    5, "ID-2", "Windows", dynamic([
        {"name": "name1", "value": true},
        {"name": "name2", "value": false},
        {"name": "name3", "value": true}
    ]), dynamic([
        {"name": "s1", "expiry": false},
        {"name": "s2", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s3", "expiry": true},
        {"name": "s4", "expiry": true}
    ])
];
```

[image: table input]

I want to filter features by `name1` and `name2`  and ScanState by `s1` and `s3` and then count the number of `VMID` for each `Type` and also give a list of `VMID` for

1. has value == true for feature.name = name1
2. has value = false for feature.name = name2
3. has expiry = false for scanState.name = s1
4. has expiry = true for scanState.name = s3

My main problem is when using `mv-apply` it breaks the JSON into multiple rows.  And doing a count() leads to extra results.

```
MyTable
| mv-apply features, scanner on (where  features.name == "name1" or features.name == "name2" or scanner.name == "s1" or scanner.name == "s3" )
| extend feature1State = tobool(features.name == "name1" and features.value == true)
| extend feature2State = tobool(features.name == "name2" and features.value == false)
| extend scan1State = tobool(scanner.name == "s1" and scanner.expiry == false)
| extend scan2State = tobool(scanner.name == "s3" and scanner.expiry == true)
| summarize vmCount = count(VMID),
    f1count = countif(feature1State == true),
    f2count= countif(feature2State== true),
    scan1count = countif(scan1State == true),
    scan2count = countif(scan2State == true),
    f1FailVm = make_set_if(VMID, feature1State == false and isnotempty( VMID)),
    f2FailVm = make_set_if(VMID, feature2State== false and isnotempty( VMID)),
    scan1FailVm = make_set_if(VMID, scan1State == false and isnotempty( VMID)),
    scan2FailVm = make_set_if(VMID, scan2State == false and isnotempty( VMID))
    by ID, Type
```

The output of it
[image: result output]

Do note that I get 6 VM Count for ID-1 which isn't right. This is due to the fact that `mv-apply` in essence created multiple rows.
Since the number of entries in `features` and `Scanner` are different so it picks the maximum of them.

Is there a better way to solve this.

Update 1: Using count_distinct solve for VMID  but how to get the right failed List value .
Output using `count_distinct`
[image: count_distinct]

Comment: Try `vmCount = count_distinct( VMID)` instead of `count(VMID)`. The `count_distinct` function is used to count the number of distinct `VMID` values by Type and Id fields.

Comment: Tried that too with that it will only solve for VMCount, but for others it doesn't as fail list will contain all the entries because one entry in the JSOn doesn't match up.

Comment: Yes, Faillist will have  vmids that has atleast one false. How do you want to display

Comment: `f1FailVM` list for `Windows` should be `[]` for ID-1 as both the rows in original table in column features have `name=name1 and value = true`

Comment: That is if that id has atleast one true, we should ignore in the fail list. Is this the requirement?

Comment: `f1failVM= set_difference(make_set_if(VMID, feature1State == false), make_set_if(VMID, feature1State == true))`

Comment: Yes, from the original table if `feature` has a matching entry ( ie name1 and true ) then it shouldn't be part of f1FailVmList , similarly for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254072/discussion-between-aswin-and-sukhmeet-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use  `vmCount = count_distinct( VMID)` instead of `count(VMID)`. The `count_distinct` function is used to count the number of distinct `VMID` values by Type and Id fields.
- `f1FailVm` field is the list of VMIDs which does not have a true in `feature1State` field in Type and Id. For this case, take the first set as the set of `VMID` values that have a `false` value in the `feature1State` field, and the second set as the set of `VMID` values that have a `true` value in the `feature1State` field and then use  `set_difference` between them.

**Code:**

```
MyTable
| mv-apply features, scanner on (where features.name == "name1" or features.name == "name2" or scanner.name == "s1" or scanner.name == "s3" )
| extend feature1State = tobool(features.name == "name1" and features.value == true)
| extend feature2State = tobool(features.name == "name2" and features.value == false)
| extend scan1State = tobool(scanner.name == "s1" and scanner.expiry == false)
| extend scan2State = tobool(scanner.name == "s3" and scanner.expiry == true)
| summarize vmCount = count_distinct( VMID),
f1count = countif(feature1State == true),
f2count= countif(feature2State== true),
scan1count = countif(scan1State == true),
scan2count = countif(scan2State == true),
f1failVM= set_difference(make_set_if(VMID, feature1State == false), make_set_if(VMID, feature1State == true)),
f2FailVM = set_difference(make_set_if(VMID, feature2State == false), make_set_if(VMID, feature2State == true)),
scan1FailVm = set_difference(make_set_if(VMID, scan1State == false), make_set_if(VMID, scan1State == true)),
scan2FailVm = set_difference(make_set_if(VMID, scan2State == false), make_set_if(VMID, scan2State == true))
by ID, Type
```

**Output:**

| ID | Type | vmCount | f1count | f2count | scan1count | scan2count | f1failVM | f2FailVM | scan1FailVm | scan2FailVm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID-1 | Windows | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | [] | [] | [] | [2] |
| ID-1 | Linux | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | [] | [] | [] | [] |
| ID-2 | Windows | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | [] | [] | [] | [4] |

[fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/ContosoSales?query=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)